# How to build a Postgres IDE in Emacs

Tags: postgresql, emacs

I noticed emacs has a `sql-postgres` mode.  It's a good start, but my needs are very different.  I usually have a large SQL file that I am editing and I want to "run" it on the database.  I would like to edit my code in Emacs, not PG Admin.  However, I am a bit more picky on how I see the results.  I would rather not see a new Emacs buffer since Emacs doesn't really do grids that well. I was thinking of popping up some program that could show me the results in a very pretty, interactive view.  Maybe something like openoffice or some custom piece of code.

I think the best method is to hack together a makefile that will automatically run the sql file against postgres (which may even allow me to jump to any errors).  Then, if the script is successful, possible pipe the results to some program.  But which program and how can I get those results to it?

Please let me know if there is a better way.  I don't want some commercial software or Windows-only freeware.  I'd prefer OpenSource.  Any advice?

Comment: I think the Makefile idea is very good.  But, I don't understand the visualisation bit of the question.  What do you mean by interactive view?  What does piping the results to some program mean?

Comment: By "interactive" I was referring to a grid view.  Emacs does not do grids very well. I was thinking of writing an external program that would show the grid.  I was considering sending the data through some sort of pipe between Emacs and the external program (probably stdin).  I am looking at Eclipse now and I think I have something that works for me.

Answer (score 4):

You could use psql on the command line and set emacs to be your editor of choice. Whenever you type `\e` in psql, it will open your editor of choice. Grid display + emacs and there's no need to write any code.